# what stops devs from changing supply of contracts?

Tags: solidity, erc-20

If someone created an erc20 token with the state variable `uint256 totalSupply = 100`, what is stopping another dev from creating a contract with that manipulates the `totalSupply` to `0`?

Would making the state variable private or internal prevent this from happening?

Even so, couldn't that attacker make a contract: `contract attackContract is totalSupply {` and manipulate it that way?

^ Asking these questions because I want to make a smart contract that holds the total supply and can transfer tokens only via contracts with access to, set by the deployer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What stops devs from changing supply of contracts?

Only one thing - others will see it in their code and simply avoid using that contract.

---

> Would making the state variable private or internal prevent this from happening?

No, the access level of a state variable (private/internal/public) determines who can read it, not who can change it. The only one who can change a state variable in a contract instance are functions **in that instance**.

---

> Even so, couldn't that attacker make `contract attackContract is totalSupply` and manipulate it that way?

You need to understand the difference between a contract and a contract instance:

A contract is just source code.

A contract instance is the bytecode of that contract deployed on the network.

Obviously, one contract can have many instances of it deployed on the network.

With `contract A is B`, when you create an instance of `B`, it is not going to extend any existing instance of `A` out there. It is going to be a "brand new" instance, which obviously cannot change the state variable of any existing instance.

Comment: Also, thank you for the great explanation :)

Comment: Ahh okay. So someone couldn't change their balance of that token or a mapping assigning an address to a boolean via a contract instance because they would need a function that does it in the source code, correct?

Comment: @Lucus: Yes, and since everything on the blockchain is public, such function would be visible for everyone to see.

Comment: So a way to mitigate that would be to have functions that change important variables, such as a user's access status, would need to be restricted to onlyOwner, correct?

Comment: @Lucus: That depends on the specific requirements of the system. For example, the total-supply of an ERC20 token shouldn't even be allowed to be changed by only-owner functions (this is, if your goal is to implement an ERC20 token with a true valid financial implication).

Comment: having both an onlyOwner mint and burn function can change the supply - but If another contract instance has the same thing but makes it public, it would not change the source code's variables would it? I'm asking because when you make another contract.sol and you import that erc20 token, it uses those variables as well.

Comment: @Lucus: Like I said, `You need to understand the difference between a contract and a contract instance`. Please read the part below that line in my answer.